# scanf function in objective-c, float and double

Tags: objective-c, scanf

I just a beginner in objective-C.

Below is a calculator of temperature.

I find a solution on the internet. The problem is the scanf.

At first, I set the f as a double, but program has problem.

So I change it to float.

May I ask what's going on on scanf function in objective-c?

Only can set character, int and float?

Another question is, what if I want to set a double, to use in another function which only accept double variable?

Thanks

## import

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

```
@autoreleasepool {
    double c;
    float f;
    NSLog(@"Please enter F temp");
    scanf("%f", &f);
    c = (f-32) / 1.8;
    //c = 1.3E-3;
    // insert code here...
    NSLog(@"The C temp is %.3f", c);

}
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use `%f` for `float` and `%lf` for `double`.  However be sure to check the return value from `scanf()` (or `sscanf()`) to ensure it parsed the correct number of values:

```
double d;
printf("Entry thy number mortal: ");
if (scanf("%lf", &d)) == 1) {
    printf("Oh that's nice, you entered %f\n", d);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice.
I still have a question, why we need to check the value from input?
In which situation, we will get a wrong value when we use scanf?
Thanks again from your advice.

Comment: If someone enters a string like `"hello"` which cannot be converted to a floating-point number.